# SSRS : Disable/Hide Parameters based on selection in another Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I Have 4 Parameters in my SSRS report.
My requirement is that one of my parameters is the main parameter and based on that parameter selection the remaining 3 parameters should display/hide in the parameter section.

Eg. My parameters are

1. Parameter 1 - which has values Market, Technology
2. Marketunit
3. Country
4. Technologies

If Market is selected in Parameter 1 I need to display only 2 & 3 (i.e) Marketunit and Country
If Technology is selected in Parameter 1 I need to display only 4 - Technologies in Parameters Section

Is it Possible in SSRS 2012 ?
[My initial view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naDRj.png)
[After selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29YL1.png)

Comment: You cannot hide parameters in SSRS. The only option is to have only 2 parameters and based on the first parameter, change the default value of the second parameter.

Comment: As mentioned you cannot hide the parameters. What you can do is having your parameter query return an empty/null value for the parameter instead of hiding, prohibiting the user making any choise in that case.

Comment: Thanks @niktrs, Yes i am already hiding the values,  thought of hiding the whole parameter section . thanks for your help